# Minimum input date value must be today

Tags: html, angular, typescript, date

I have an input of type date, and I need that it is not possible to select a date that is not from today, I tried it this way, but I was not very successful:

HTML:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="atv.dataini" type="date" class="form-control" #one min="{{this.today}}">
```

TYPESCRIPT:

```
today = this.dNow.getFullYear() + '-0' + (this.dNow.getMonth() + 1) + '-0' + this.dNow.getDate();
```

I also tried it this way:

HTML:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="atv.dataini" type="date" class="form-control" #one min="{{this.tdNow}}">
```

TYPESCRIPT:

```
dNow = this.formatDate(new Date());

formatDate(date) {
    let result = date.split('-').reverse().join('/');
    return result
}
```

Comment: I can't disable it, I have to let the user select a date

Comment: But the user cannot select ONLY dates from today backwards, from today onwards, he can select freely

Comment: I know you have already accepted an answer; just wanted to share another solution as well. Let me know your thoughts, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I mean you have some ways to do that, but I guess the most correct one is to let the user input a data, and compare with the daynow, and show a message.

To get the daynow on JS:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

I think that's can help too:

[Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The complete solution would be along the lines of:

.html

```
<input #dateInput type="date" [(ngModel)]="myDate">
```

.ts

```
@ViewChild("dateInput", { static: false }) input: ElementRef;
myDate: string;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  const keyUpObservable = fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, "change");
  keyUpObservable
    .pipe(
      map((event: any) => event.target.value),
      debounceTime(2000),
      distinctUntilChanged()
    )
    .subscribe((date: string) => {
      const today = new Date();
      if (new Date(date.toString()) < today) {
        this.myDate = today.toISOString().split("T")[0];
      } else {
        this.myDate = date;
      }
    });
}
```

- Here, a reference of the input box is obtained and an observable is
  created on the *change* event (either by pressing a key or by click).
- Next,
  [`debounceTime`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounceTime)
  is used to emit this value when the user has stopped typing after 2s. (You can edit the delay based on your preferences)
- The
  [`distinctUntilChanged`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/distinctUntilChanged)
  prevents the observable from being emitted if there is no change
  between the current and previous input values.

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-directive-13).